# Quick way to form a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of points {x,y} given by the following:

```
LIST1 = {{2, 10}, {4, 12}, {6, 17}, {8, 20}, {10, 25}, {12, 23}, {14, 
32}, {16, 34}, {16, 33}, {18, 56}, {20, 43}, {22, 67}, {24, 55}};
```

I have a function defined as `MYFUN[x_,y_]=2y^2 - 4x +1`. I want to compute the value of this fucntion for every pair of (x,y) given in LIST1 and form the  `LIST2 = {x,MYFUN[x,y]}`. Is there a quick way of doing this? I tried by putting each point in the function, but it takes lot of time.

```
MYFUN = 2 (12  )^2 - 4 (4)  + 1


 LIST2 = {{2, 193}, {4, 
    273}, {6,}, {8,}, {10,}, {12,}, {14,}, {16,}, {18,}, {20,}, \
{22,}, {24,}};
```

I don't know why I gave this question a horrible title before " Parameter as a variable".

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial about defining function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) and this [tutorial about applying functions to stuff](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsToPartsOfExpressions.html). Both of them should be really easy to find in the documentation as well.

Comment: You can do it like this: `myFun[x_, y_] := 2 y^2 - 4 x + 1;
Transpose@{list1[[;; , 1]], myFun @@@ list1}`. Usually, user defined functions and variables start with a lower-case letter to differentiate from the built-in functions.

Comment: @Sascha, thanks. I just wanted to know whether I could get my LIST2 by some quick way.

Comment: Easiest to understand is maybe define your function to receive a `{x, y}` tuple as in `myFun[{x_, y_}] := 2 y^2 - 4 x + 1` and then map this function to your list of tuples via `Map[myFun]@LIST1`. If you also want every `x` together with the result you can wrap this in another function and map the resulting function: `Map[Function[p, {First[p], myFun[p]}]]@LIST1`

Answer (score 4):

```
MYFUN = {#, 2 #2^2 - 4 # + 1} &;
MYFUN @@@ LIST1
```

> {{2, 193}, {4, 273}, {6, 555}, {8, 769}, {10, 1211}, {12, 1011}, {14, 
>     1993}, {16, 2249}, {16, 2115}, {18, 6201}, {20, 3619}, {22, 
>     8891}, {24, 5955}}

`a @@@ b` means `Apply[a, b, {1}]`. For large lists, this will be more efficient:

```
Transpose[MYFUN @@ Transpose[LIST1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

For better or worse, `Map` is my default for anything over a list. Define

```
LIST1 = {{2, 10}, {4, 12}, {6, 17}, {8, 20}, {10, 25}, {12, 23}, {14, 
    32}, {16, 34}, {16, 33}, {18, 56}, {20, 43}, {22, 67}, {24, 55}};
MYFUN[x_, y_] = 2 y^2 - 4 x + 1
```

Then using `Map` (`/@`) and `Apply` (`@@`)

```
{#[[1]], MYFUN @@ ##} & /@ LIST1
```

> {{2, 193}, {4, 273}, {6, 555}, {8, 769}, {10, 1211}, {12, 1011}, {14, 
>     1993}, {16, 2249}, {16, 2115}, {18, 6201}, {20, 3619}, {22, 
>     8891}, {24, 5955}}

Answer (score 2):

```
 MYFUN[x_, y_] = 2 y^2 - 4 x + 1  
{#, MYFUN[##]} & @@@ LIST1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid uppercase variables and function names, [see this answer.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/10397)

Also, look at the documentation for [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) as an alternative to the other solutions.

```
list1 = {{2, 10}, {4, 12}, {6, 17}, {8, 20}, {10, 25}, {12, 23}, {14, 
    32}, {16, 34}, {16, 33}, {18, 56}, {20, 43}, {22, 67}, {24, 55}};

ClearAll[myfunc];
myfunc[{x_, y_}] := {x, 2 y^2 - 4 x + 1}

Thread@myfunc@list1
(* {{2, 193}, {4, 273}, {6, 555}, {8, 769}, {10, 1211}, {12, 
  1011}, {14, 1993}, {16, 2249}, {16, 2115}, {18, 6201}, {20, 
  3619}, {22, 8891}, {24, 5955}} *)
```